# Как установить тип сети постоянно в Windows 10?

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10, типы, подсети

**Как установить тип сети постоянно в Windows 10?**

Мне каждый раз приходится менять тип сети.
`Power Shell` - от имени администратора

Установка публичной сети

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex номер_интерфейса -Networkcategory Public
```

Установка частной сети

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex номер_интерфейса -Networkcategory Private
```

`get-NetConnectionProfile` //просмотреть профили сетей.

Если сетей много, то нужно каждый раз менять их тип.

Вопрос: Как задать тип сети на определенном интерфейсе постоянно?
Как это сделать из командной строки или в regedit.
Дело в том, что GUI на разных сборках Windows 10 отличаются и нужен какой-то более универсальный способ.

Comment: `Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private` - текущая сеть объявляется приватной. Плюс: не надо указывать интерфейс или название сети. Минус: тока для одной сети.

Comment: Какая сеть считается текущей? И опять же это действует в текущем сеансе пользователя? То есть изменения не сохраняются после перезагрузки?

Comment: Текущая - которая вот прям щас. Нет. Это пишется в систему и сохраняется после.

Comment: Как узнать с помощью скрипта какая текущая? Где это сохраняется в системе? После перезагрузки ничего не сохраняется. В каком месте системы это сохраняется? Может проще найти значение реестра и поправить там?  Но где?

Comment: Если я выставлю secpol.msc/Политика диспетчера списка сетей/Неопознанные сети  = личное, то обе сети станут частными, если я выставлю = общее, то обе сети станут общественными. Я имею в виду после перезагрузки. А мне нужно чтобы одна сеть была частная, а другая общественная

Comment: В реестре править не вариант, потому что там в пути есть `uuid`. Если после перезагрузки не сохраняется - у тебя чё-то с ОС. УМВР на свежеустановленной. Говорю это, потому что собираю образ через ansible\winrm, а на доступ как раз влияет частная\публичная. Как узнать с помощью скрипта - ну наверное `Get-NetConnectionProfile` (винды под рукой нет - проверить не могу).

Comment: Get-NetConnectionProfile покажет несколько профилей, если больше одной сетки. И не скажет какая сетка текущая.  Ну можно же как-то uuid определить и  поправить через такую идентификацию. Настройки слетают после перезагрузки. Нужно каким-то образом сделать их постоянными. Ну или запретить системе менять определенный ключ реестра. Но какой?

Comment: Ещё раз. Если настройки слетают - какая-то хрень с осью. Накати на виртуалку чистую и проверь там - всё будет сохраняться нормально.